# Values from ng-repeat are overflowing past the screen size in Responsive View: AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Problem with my approach is when the device width shrinks or switch my view to Mobile View, the chips are overflowing past the screen size. I wanted the chips to be aligned responsively with the screen size.

I tried implementing the `div` with flex but not luck.

Here's the code

```
  <div layout="row">
    <div layout="row">
      <md-chips ng-repeat="filter in filters" readOnly="true">
        <md-chip class="chipStyling">
          {{filter.name}}
        </md-chip>
      </md-chips>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I created a [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/GVdpWG?editors=1001) to show the working example. Could anyone please review and let me know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: It is irrelevant to my question. I don't want to know the device resolution. I need help on the css part of my code which should solve my problem. @mewi

Comment: So you want the chips to wrap rather than cut off? If so just wrap it in a bootstrap container https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with adding flex, but you needed to tell it to wrap as well. On the second row, you can add the following css..

```
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
```

Comment: Ahh Perfect! This is it.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Angular Material, but just looking at the docs, it seems you can add the `flex-wrap:wrap` by adding `layout-wrap` to the container element

```
<div layout="row">
 <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <md-chips ng-repeat="filter in filters" readOnly="true">
    <md-chip class="chipStyling">
      {{filter.name}}
    </md-chip>
  </md-chips>
</div>
```